# SDL 2.0 How to generate texture on top of everything?

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm doing this Frogger type of game and I want to display a texture on certain coordinates when player approaches the "win" position. 
This is what the game looks like:
[image: my game]

In red circles is space where the "win" texture should be rendered (just a texture of "ok thumb") after achieving this position by frog player. Also, this texture should stay on "win" position until game ends, two options: 
-> until the player loses all 3 lifes
-> until the player occupies all 5 "win" positions
Now, some code.
This is from main(), part containing all render stuff:

```
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 2, 100, 64, 1);
                SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer);
                SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, plansza, NULL, &otherRect[2]);
                renderMovingObjects(enemiesRect, alliesRect);
                SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, frog, NULL, &otherRect[0]);
                renderHearts(lives);
                checkIfWon(&otherRect[0], &lives, &play, &places);
                //renderWonPosition(300, 500); //explanation below
                SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);
```

Here is the checkIfWon() function, this just checks if the player is on "win" position, and if yes - it should generate "win" texture and then reset player position to continue the game inside the gameOver() function.

```
void checkIfWon(SDL_Rect* frogRect, int* lives, bool* play, int *places)
{
static bool pos1 = false, pos2 = false, pos3 = false, pos4 = false, pos5 = false;
if (*places == 0)
    pos1 = pos2 = pos3 = pos4 = pos5 = false;
if (frogRect->y == 50 + (SCREEN_HEIGHT % 100))
{
    if (frogRect->x > 29 && frogRect->x < 61)
    {   
        checkIfPositionWon(&pos1, places, lives);
        renderWonPosition(frogRect->x, frogRect->y);  //HERE should render "win" texture
        gameOver(frogRect, lives, play, places);
    }
    else if (frogRect->x > 169 && frogRect->x < 201)
    {
        checkIfPositionWon(&pos2, places, lives);
        renderWonPosition(frogRect->x, frogRect->y);   // it's pretty much same else if's 5 times
        gameOver(frogRect, lives, play, places);       // for 5 different positions
    }
    else if (frogRect->x > 309 && frogRect->x < 341)
    {
        checkIfPositionWon(&pos3, places, lives);
        renderWonPosition(frogRect->x, frogRect->y);
        gameOver(frogRect, lives, play, places);
    }
    else if (frogRect->x > 449 && frogRect->x < 481)
    {
        checkIfPositionWon(&pos4, places, lives);
        renderWonPosition(frogRect->x, frogRect->y);
        gameOver(frogRect, lives, play, places);
    }
    else if (frogRect->x > 589 && frogRect->x < 621)
    {
        checkIfPositionWon(&pos5, places, lives);
        renderWonPosition(frogRect->x, frogRect->y);
        gameOver(frogRect, lives, play, places);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("LOST LIFE!\n");
        gameOver(frogRect, lives, play, places);
    }

    if (*places == 5) //the player occupied all five "win" positions and the game ends
        gameOver(frogRect, lives, play, places);
}
}
```

Here is the function which renders "win" texture on specific coordinates:

```
void renderWonPosition(int x, int y)
{
  SDL_Rect wonPosition = { x, y, 50, 50 };
  SDL_RenderSetViewport(gRenderer, &wonPosition);
  SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, ok, NULL, NULL);
  SDL_Rect undoView = { 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT };
  SDL_RenderSetViewport(gRenderer, &undoView);
}
```

Now...
       My problem is, this function doesn't render the texture permanently, only for like a second snapshot or so. I debugged this and inside renderWonPosition() passed values were okay. My concern is, why, when I call the same renderWonPosition() function inside main() with some random int parameters, this works and renders "win" texture, but when this function is called form inside checkIfWon() texture stays only for a second?

Answer (score 1):

It is disappearing because you only render it for the one instance/frame that the character has won. Most rendering nowadays is done on some sort of framebuffer. This is what ends up getting viewed by the user on the screen. Framebuffers can have different formats for different uses, but generally it is just that, a buffer. In the general case it is a buffer representing a 2D image of pixels.

What happens is you don't draw to the same buffer each time, or if you do you clear it to a single static color each time. As you can see in the code you posted.

```
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 2, 100, 64, 1);

        SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer); // <---- this clears the buffer to a solid color

        SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, plansza, NULL, &otherRect[2]);
        renderMovingObjects(enemiesRect, alliesRect);
        SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, frog, NULL, &otherRect[0]);
        renderHearts(lives);
        checkIfWon(&otherRect[0], &lives, &play, &places);
        //renderWonPosition(300, 500); //explanation below
        SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);
```

So now the problem is `checkIfWon` will only call renderWonPosition() one time. That is when the player is in the position. I'll assume `gameOver()` moves the player out of that position when it resets the game correct? So now the next time this loop goes through `renderWonPosition()` isn't called as the player isn't in that position anymore.

So you are going to have to make sure you render the "Won" texture every frame/loop. So basically if your variables `pos1/pos2/etc...` are true, then you should be calling `renderWonPosition()`.

---

That being said, you could definitely improve the checkIfWon function as a result. I don't know what some of your other variables do, but judging by the variable `places` you are doing a lot of extra work because your variables `pos1/pos2/...` are hidden inside the `checkIfWon()` function.

You can do something like this:

```
#include <vector>

struct WinningPosition {
    // used to check the bounds if the frog is in this position
    // frog->x > this->x && frog->x < this->x + Width
    static constexpr int Width = 32;

    // the x, y position that the frag can be in to win
    int x;
    int y;
    bool won = false;
};

void renderWonPosition(int x, int y) {
    // todo render
}

void handleWinningPositions(SDL_Rect* frogRect, std::vector<WinningPosition>& positions) {
    // we loop through all the possible positions
    for (auto& pos : positions) {
        // if the position is already won then we render it
        // to the screen and continue as we don't need to check it again
        if (pos.won) {
            renderWonPosition(pos.x, pos.y);
            continue;
        }


        // this might need to be looked at, I just took it from your code
        // but checking an exact position might not be the best approach
        // for example, if the frog can move more than 1 pixel at a time
        // assuming that frogRect->y is measured in pixels
        if (frogRect->y == 50 + (SCREEN_HEIGHT % 100))
        {
            if (frogRect->x > pos.x && frogRect->x < pos.x + WinningPosition::Width)
            {
                pos.won = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // Here you could check if the game is over,
    // if all the above positions are set to true or if no
    // lives remaining

    // checkIfPositionWon(&pos2, places, lives);
    // gameOver(frogRect, lives, play, places);

}


// ...

    // here we simply store all the positions that are winnable
    // we set which this position is to be rendered or 
    // where the frog needs to be in order for it to be considered a win
    std::vector<WinningPosition> winningPositions = {
        WinningPosition{ 29, 50 /* you'd need to calcluate the Y position */ },
        WinningPosition{ 169, 50 },
    };

    handleWinningPositions(frogPos, winningPositions);

// ...
```

Anyways games are pretty difficult to program. They become very complicated and a lot of the components of a game need to know about each other. I can only see a fraction of the code you have so I don't know how everything else operates. Hopefully this gives some more ideas of what you can do. This way it's really easy to add more positions and you are less likely to make a mistake in the logic for determining if the frog is in the win position. And ultimately you write less code which is less work to maintain :).

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Unfortunately I'm a little scared of vectors because I was always doing something in pure C, but maybe now it's time to learn it... I created global pos1/pos2 .. variables and then added function which renders stuff on "win position" inside my Render() function, based on the fact if certain position was already occupied. You gave me the idea that the variables 'pos' must be somehow seen in main(), so now it works! Maybe not in the prettiest way, but works... :)